# Python - how to get nan

Tags: python, nan

I know I can get nan in Python by

```
>>>float("nan")
nan
```

But is there any other way of getting it without "nan"? Like in Javascript, I can do

```
>"something"-1
NaN
```

Can I do something simillar in Python?
Thanks.

Comment: you will get `TypeError`, `nan` can be obtained by dividing infinities (e. g. `float('inf)` and `-float('inf)`)

Comment: If you have access to NumPy, you could do `np.int16(1)/0 - np.int16(1)/0` or merely use `numpy.nan`, but that's less fun, isn't it?

Comment: [*"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) Why do you need *another* way to get NaN?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Python 3.5 or later, `NaN` is available as the constant `math.nan`:

```
import math
print(math.nan) # nan
```

In earlier versions, you can get NaN only by casting it from string:

```
print(float('NaN')) # nan
```

Or by trying to do weird operations on infinity:

```
print(float('Inf') - float('Inf')) # nan
```

You can also use the `numpy` library. However, numpy is a big library and you shouldn't use it just for this.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.nan) # nan
```

Comment: `numpy` is a big library, but you could of course just import nan by itself. `from numpy import nan`.

Comment: @zephyr I think what they meant is that you shouldn't install the whole package only to get nan. But I agree, if it's already available then importing nan alone is the best solution.